# Can someone help me with this onclick/if else?

Tags: if-statement, onclick, image-resizing

Okay, so I'm pretty new at Javascript, and I want to be able to re-size an image onclick. That said, I want to be able to click the image once, obtain a size and click it again and make it return to it's original size.

Right now, I have this:

```
function QrClick(){
var Qr = document.getElementById("qrCode");

if (Qr.style.width="150px") {
    Qr.style.height="50px";
    Qr.style.width="50px";}

else {Qr.style.height="150px";
    Qr.style.width="150px";}

}
```

To me, newbie as I am, this looks like it could work. I can see why this isn't working, but I need a solution. It's actually something that's been bothering me for a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong operator. == is equality = is assigment.

```
function QrClick(){
var Qr = document.getElementById("qrCode");

if (Qr.style.width=="150px") {
    Qr.style.height="50px";
    Qr.style.width="50px";}

else {Qr.style.height=="150px";
    Qr.style.width="150px";}

}
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Oh my god. You'd think I would have realized that by now, but, oh my god, thank you. Like I said, this has honestly been bugging me for a while.